# AngularJS filter unique removing duplicates in ng-options

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, filter, ng-options

i have an array:

```
$scope.arr1 = [option1, option2, option3, option1, option3]
```

I am using it to fill select options:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="arr1"
     ng-options="option for option in arr1">
     <option value="" disabled>Please select an option</option>
</select>
```

the options are populated but i want to remove duplicates from them. i have tried:

```
ng-options="option for option in arr1 | unique: 'option'"
```

but it gives empty results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular does not provide any out of the box filter to achieve what you need.

You tried using `ng-options="option for option in arr1 | unique: 'option'"`,  but in angular there is no filter called `unique`.

You might want to look at the available filters in angular [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter).

To get the result you want, you will want to create your custom filter to do that. I have created a snippet below which will filter common values. This should work for you.

```js
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
app.controller("testCntrl", function($scope){
  $scope.arr1 = ['option1','option2','option3','option1','option3'];
  
})
.filter("removeDups", function(){
  return function(data) {
    if(angular.isArray(data)) {
      var result = [];
      var key = {};
      for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        var val = data[i];
        if(angular.isUndefined(key[val])) {
          key[val] = val;
          result.push(val);
        }
      }
      if(result.length > 0) {
        return result;
      }
    }
    return data;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="testCntrl">
<select class="form-control" ng-model="arr"
     ng-options="option for option in arr1 | removeDups">
     <option value="" disabled>Please select an option</option>
</select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`unique` is not included with AngularJS - [this filter](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-OLDREPO/blob/master/modules/filters/unique/unique.js) is bundled with older versions on AngularUI, and also appears to be commonly available at [a8m/angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter). You can retrofit it within your app, roll your own, or include a providing module. Observe the following...

```
ng-options="option for option in arr1 | unique"
```

---

```
// -- AngularUI implementation
.filter('unique', function () {

  return function (items, filterOn) {

    if (filterOn === false) {
      return items;
    }

    if ((filterOn || angular.isUndefined(filterOn)) && angular.isArray(items)) {
      var hashCheck = {}, newItems = [];

      var extractValueToCompare = function (item) {
        if (angular.isObject(item) && angular.isString(filterOn)) {
          return item[filterOn];
        } else {
          return item;
        }
      };

      angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
        var valueToCheck, isDuplicate = false;

        for (var i = 0; i < newItems.length; i++) {
          if (angular.equals(extractValueToCompare(newItems[i]), extractValueToCompare(item))) {
            isDuplicate = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (!isDuplicate) {
          newItems.push(item);
        }

      });
      items = newItems;
    }
    return items;
  };
});
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/y6gs6gmc/) - working demo